# Initial Value Problem Differential Equation

Tags: differential

Im am confused on how to do Initial Value Problems involved differential equations. Particularly, this one.
$$
{{\rm dP}\left(t\right) \over {\rm d}t}=4\left({\rm e}^{t - 1} + t\right)\,,
\qquad
{\rm P}\left(1\right) = 20
$$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate both sides:
$$P(t)=2t^2+4e^{t-1}+C$$
Use the condition $P(1)=20$:
$$20=2*1^2+4e^{1-1}+C$$
$$20=2+4+C$$
$$C=14$$
So the final equation is:
$$P(t)=2t^2+4e^{t-1}+14$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrate both sides:

$P(t) = 2t^2 + 4e^{t-1} + C $

$\rightarrow 2 + 4 + C = 20$

$\rightarrow C = 14$

$\therefore P(t) = 2t^2 + 4e^{t-1} + 14.$